# How to apply Twig filters to form_label(form.name), e.g. 'capitalize'?

Tags: symfony, twig

My problem concerns just applying Twig filter inside a form without getting a 500 server error. Here is the code, which is in the view 'Room/new.html.twig':

```
{{ form_label(form.name) }}
```

or

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'room.name') }}
```

Both will output: 'nom de salle' ('room name' in French). That is because, in my translation file 'messages.fr.yml', I have:

```
room.name: "nom de salle"
```

Also, I activated the translation in my form type 'RoomType.php' with this code:

```
->add('name', 'text', array(
 'label' => 'room.name'
```

))

I tried every possible combination I thought of with |capitalize and got either a 500 server error or no change at all. Some examples:

```
{{ form_label(form.name)|capitalize }}
{{ form_label(form.name, 'room.name'|capitalize) }}
```

and so many more...

Does anyone know how to do it, it doesn't seem to be in the Symfony doc. Of course, I thought about duplicating the translation to have one in lower case and one starting with a capital letter but that would defeat the object. Plus there are other Twig filters I would like to use with this form_label() function.
Help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I forgot to precise that I am working with the latest version of Symfony 2.6. I also use regularly many Twig filters like |trans or |capitalize in views and it always works. The problem is only with this form_label() function. That is strange because phpStorm does the auto-completion but the code still fails. And I didn't forget to empty the cache ....

Answer (score 5):

I just found the solution. It's so easy that it is embarrassing. I thought I didn't need the |trans as it was already translated but without it, 'room.name' = 'nom de salle' would transform to 'Room.name' instead of 'Nom de salle'. So the correct code is just:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'room.name'|trans|capitalize) }}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you happen to know how to capitalize inside the FormType file? When you have a line like `title => something.something`  then it will not get capitalized, obviously, but you can't use `ucfirst` neither since it won't translate the string and just uppercase it literally.